# ARM - Link register in exception

Tags: exception, assembly, arm

I have this code for an IRQ exception for my raspberry pi:

```
push {r0-r12, lr}

mov r1, r11
str r1, [r0, #GPIO_EVT_STAT0]
ldr r5, =State
ldr r2, [r5]
tst r2, #0x01
streq r12, [r0, #GPIO_OUT_CLR0]
strne r12, [r0, #GPIO_OUT_SET0]
mvn r2, r2
str r2, [r5]

pop  {r0-r12, lr}
subs pc, lr, #0x04
```

The ARM manual says, that the link register (r14) is banked in the different modes. So I don´t have to push the link register onto the stack. Is this correct?

When I try this code (same as above, but without pushing the link register)

```
push {r0-r12}

mov r1, r11
str r1, [r0, #GPIO_EVT_STAT0]
ldr r5, =State
ldr r2, [r5]
tst r2, #0x01
streq r12, [r0, #GPIO_OUT_CLR0]
strne r12, [r0, #GPIO_OUT_SET0]
mvn r2, r2
str r2, [r5]

pop  {r0-r12}
subs pc, lr_irq, #0x04
```

I get this error during compilation:

```
source/main.s:121: Error: immediate expression requires a # prefix -- `subs pc,lr_irq,#0x04'
```

So why do I get this error? My understanding is that r14 is banked in the IRQ-Mode and the banked registers get accessed by the notation `register_mode`.

Comment: I don't think you can use the banked registers like that. Try `MRS` to access it.

Comment: lr_irq is just lr when in irq mode.  It uses the same opcode and hence the same assembler.  Lr_irq is only for manuals to denote a banked value.

Comment: Fine, thank you :)
This is the answer i´m looking for.